# Regex help for MediaWiki template markup

Tags: .net, regex, mediawiki

My regex skills are pretty poor, and most of the time they make me feel stupid. Can anyone help?

This question is more concerned with better mastery of regex than the job of extracting information from mud soup, so if my understanding of the mediawiki template system is flawed, I don't really mind that much. I'll spot it soon enough.

I'm parsing MediaWiki markup, and I'm trying to grab MediaWiki template names. These denoted by something like:

**{{Template Name|other stuff**

or

**{{Template Name}}**

If a # immediately follows the braces :

**{{#Other thing**

I'd like to ignore it.

So...

I'd like to match 2 curly braces {{ not followed by # up until the next occurrence of either | (pipe) or }} (2 closing curlies)

So:

**{{I am a frog|some other stuff**        *match*

**{{#I am a frog|some other stuff**       *fail*

**garbage here{{Monkey}}bla bla** *match*

**garbage here{{#Monkey}}bla bla** *fail*

etc...

The following regex covers this (I think):

```
\{{2}(?!\#)(.*?)(?:\||\}\})
```

but also matches:

**some stuff here {{{Giraffe|oijq**

How can I make it fail if there are not exactly 2 opening curly braces?

EDIT: .net regex, btw

Comment: what you are doing is kind of on the bounds of regex's comfort zone. You can do it, but you will end up putting so much effort into it, that you probably want to create a light weight parser. That way as you install new syntaxes and nest them, you don't end up running in circles

Comment: what should {{{blah}}} render as or result as?

Comment: I know. Regex really sucks for this, but the level of info I need from the doc is really small, and I need to process them quick, so I really can't afford to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use a [zero-width negative lookbehind/ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

> Lookbehind has the same effect, but
>   works backwards. It tells the regex
>   engine to temporarily step backwards
>   in the string, to check if the text
>   inside the lookbehind can be matched
>   there. `(?<!a)b` matches a "b" that is
>   not preceded by an "a", using negative
>   lookbehind. It will not match "cab", but
>   will match the b (and only the b) in
>   "bed" or "debt". `(?<=a)b` (positive
>   lookbehind) matches the b (and only
>   the b) in cab, but does not match bed
>   or debt.

So:

```
(?<!\{)\{{2}?(?!\#)(.*?)(?:\||\}\})
```

The other issue I just noticed, the `(.*?)` would match the third curly...  Instead, try adding the third curly to the negative lookahead you are using for # already

```
(?<!\{)\{{2}(?!\{*\#|\{+)(.*?)(?:\||\}\})
```

Comment: Same as my comment to Dav. That doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: updated answer - not sure if you'll need to escape the # or { in a set, i don't think you need to.

Comment: OK. Giving you answer as you were correct about (.*?) matching the third brace, which took me to the answer. Ended up with the following : (?<!\{)\{{2}(?!\{*\#|\{+)(.*?)(?:\||\}\})

Comment: Cool - Editing the Answer to include that as the last example

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<!\{)\{{2}(?!\#)(.*?)(?:\||\}\})
```

The zero-width negative look-behind

```
(?<!\{)
```

only matches a position that is not directly after a curly brace.

Answer (score 0):

A maybe hackish wau would basically do a OR NOT with the same regex pattern repeated, except make it match 3 or more curly braces.  Probably not the most elegant solution though.  Good luck.